# Flink reduce keyed non-windowed stream

Tags: apache-flink

I am using keyed, non window stream.
Trying to reduce the above streamed objects into one by reducing both the values into one by summing up a variable in that object and returning that object. Below is the example

For example, there are two objects, object1 and object2 both having count variable.

```
object1 -> 
    name
    count
object2 ->
    name
    count
```

Flink keyed non-window reduce function is actually not reducing and returning one object. It is returning both the objects: object1 as is and object2 with updated count

```
deDupedStream.keyBy(msg -> keyConstruct())
.reduce((ReduceFunction<Object>) (value1, value2) -> {
    value2.setCount(value1.getCount() + value2.getCount());
    return value2;
})
```

the above outputs:

```
actual:
value1 -> object with no change
value2 -> object with updated count

expectation:
value2 -> object with updated count
```

What I was expecting to return only the updated object but not both. That is what I assume as reduce. Could anyone please suggest how can I output only the updated one?

Update: Logic before the above aggregation step: Deduplication.

```
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Object> deDupedStream = inputStream.keyBy(new DeDupKeyConstructor())
                .timeWindow(Time.milliseconds(timeWindowInMillis))
                .reduce(new DedupReduceFunction(), new DedupProcessFunction());
```

DedupeProcessFunction.java

```
public class DedupProcessFunction extends ProcessWindowFunction<Class1, Class1, String, TimeWindow> {

    @Override
    public void process(String key, Context context, Iterable<Class1> in, Collector<Class1> out) throws Exception {
        Class1 obj = in.iterator().next();
        obj.setWindowStartTime(context.window().getStart());
        out.collect(obj);
    }
}
```

DedupeReduceFunction.java

```
public class DedupReduceFunction implements ReduceFunction<Class1> {
    @Override
    public Class1 reduce(Class1 value1, Class1 value2) throws Exception {
        return value1.getEventTimeStamp() > value2.getEventTimeStamp() ? value1 : value2;
    }
}
```

The above stream is actually collection the data of 1 hour and removing duplicates among them

Below, I am trying to perform aggregation. What actually I was trying is, Will I be able to combine both logic into one window. Let's also assume both the key constructors are same. If I try to combine both into one window logic, I can reduce the number of operators in the job. This is how I started to play around to remove one window and see how it is behaving. If that is not possible, how can I combine two logics into one (assuming the key grouping logic is nearly same (just one variable gets removed in aggregateKeyConstructor from DeDupKeyConstructor)).

```
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Object> aggregatedStream = deDupedStream
.keyBy(aggregateKeyConstructor())
.timeWindow(Time.milliseconds(timeWindowInMillis))
.reduce(new AggregateReduceFunction(), new AggregateProcessFunction());
```

AggregateProcessFunction.java

```
public class AggregateProcessFunction extends ProcessWindowFunction<Class1, Class1, String, TimeWindow> {

    @Override
    public void process(String key, Context context, Iterable<Class1> in, Collector<Class1> out) throws Exception {
        out.collect(in.iterator().next());
    }
}
```

AggregateReduceFunction.java

```
public class AggregateReduceFunction implements ReduceFunction<Class1> {
    @Override
    public Class1 reduce(Class1 value1, Class1 value2) {
        Class1 value =  value1.getEventTimeStamp() > value2.getEventTimeStamp() ? value1 : value2;
        value.setCount(value1.getCount() + value2.getCount());
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a _rolling_ reduce: when the first element comes along, there's nothing to reduce it with yet, so it is emitted as the initial value. If you expect a single value here, how many would you expect when it's three, four, ... elements to reduce rather than two?

Comment: I still expect only one object as output if there are N objects in that keyed group.

Comment: My thought is, is there a choice not to emit the first object, but only emit the updated object. I am checking the possibility without using the window.

Comment: If N objects in the same keyed group should still result in a single output, the next logical question is: how do you know when the last element of a keyed group has arrived in an unbounded stream, so that you can now emit the result? I think you need to answer that question for your use case and then implement a custom rich function that does the aggregation.

Comment: I now see what you are saying. I dint provide the whole code, felt may be was not needed. But with your question, I should include that logic. Let me update the question with what I am doing before this aggregation

Comment: I have updated my current code how I am using aggregation. It looks like removing a window wont help me in getting what I want. But combining both window logic into one is what I think I need.